# Custom Linux Kernel Module Can't be Inserted in WSL 2

Tags: kernel, compiling, windows-subsystem-for-linux, makefile

OS: Windows 11, WSL2(Ubuntu 22.04)

inside WSL2, command `uname -r` returns: `5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2`

Firstly, I dowloaded the correct version of Linux kernel from Github: [WSL2-Linux-Kernel](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel). Then I compiled and installed it, and created a soft link from /lib/modules to /usr/src with this command:

`sudo ln -s /lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 /usr/src/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2`

I wrote a custom kernel module with C: `hello.c`, with a Makefile like below:

```
obj-m := hello.o

all:make -C /usr/src/`uname -r` M=$PWD modules

clean:make -C /usr/src/`uname -r` M=$PWD clean
```

inside the same path of `hello.c`, I use this command to build the `hello.ko` file:

```
make -C /usr/src/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD
```

And then the `hello.ko` file was successfully generated. But when I ran the command `insmod hello.ko` it threw an error like this:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module hello.ko: Invalid module format
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Well, what is the `hello.c` code? Presumably you have something wrong there.

Comment: The `hello.c` file only contains two printk() functions.

Comment: Still, please show us the code so we can try to reproduce this. Also, you haven't followed the process described in [Compiling kernel modules](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/kernel_modules.html#compiling-kernel-modules). You aren't using the `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build` directory, and aren't using the same compiler flags. I don't really know anything about kernel modules, and veeeeeery little about C, but since you are being told the format is invalid, I suspect it will be because of these differences.